# C# winforms Data bind textboxes to wcf request

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm currently trying to parse a request from my Customer-Class into a winform.
I am getting the content through a WCF service i've built.

Here is the Form1 code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();  
        int valueParsed;
        if(txt_KNr.TextLength == 6)
        {
            if(Int32.TryParse(txt_KNr.Text.Trim(), out valueParsed))
            {
                Service svc = new Service();
                WcfServiceGVO.CustomerData data = svc.Connect(txt_KNr.Text);
                dict = svc.SplitData(data);
                txt_FirstName.DataBindings.Add("Text", data, "FirstName", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
                txt_LastName.DataBindings.Add("Text", data, "LastName");
                txt_Street.DataBindings.Add("Text", data, "Street");
                txt_PLZ.DataBindings.Add("Text", data, "PLZ");
                txt_Location.DataBindings.Add("Text", data, "Location");
                lbl_ampErg.DataBindings.Add("Text", data, "Ampel");
            }}
```

Here is part of the Reference.cs

```
        public string LastName {
        get {
            return this.LastNameField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.LastNameField, value) != true)) {
                this.LastNameField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("LastName");
            }
        }
    }
```

It works the first time, but the second time the compiler says there are 2 bindings (so i guess my DataBindings shouldn't be in the button_Click but under InitializeComponent();)
If i do that, the code runs but won't update the textboxes. What do i need to change, so that the textboxes get updated as soon as my request gets the data from the server? If the property is changed, it should update the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1 - Quick Fix**

A quick fix would be clearing `DataBindings` collection before adding a new `Binding`.

**Option 2 - Using BindingSource in Code**

You can create a `BindingSource` in code and set type of your model as it's `DataSource`, then perform data binding to the `BindingSource` in code. Then when loading data, just assign data to `DataSource` property of the binding source. For example:

```
private BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bindingSource1.DataSource = typeof(Model1);
    this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "Property1", true,
                                    DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation);
    this.textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "Property2", true,  
                                    DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bindingSource1.DataSource = GetData();
}
```

**Option 3 - Designer Support**

You can use a [`BindingSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h974h4y2(v=vs.110).aspx) component for data binding at design-time.
You can put a `BindingSource` component on your form and set it's data source property at design-time to the desired type. Then you will have design-time support for data binding using designer. You can bind your text boxes and labels to that binding source. Then when loading data, it's enough to assign data to `DataSource` property of `BindingSource`.

More Information:

- [Add new data sources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s2t4x15.aspx) specially this part [Data sources for services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s2t4x15.aspx#Anchor_1)
- [How to: Bind Data Returned by a Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907578.aspx#Anchor_4)

Comment: The first Option surely will solve your problem. For the second option read this link: [Add new data sources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s2t4x15.aspx) specially this part [Data sources for services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s2t4x15.aspx#Anchor_1)

Comment: The steps are very simple, as soon as you add a service reference to your project, it adds the required types to `DataSource` window. You also can add items manually to the window. Then in you even can drathe windows, using the dropdown near the `CustomerData`  you can choose `Details` mode and drag the `CustomerData` and drop on the form and you will see it puts a `BindingSource` and setup data-bindings for you and you cab change them if you need. Then it's enough to get data at run-time and assign to `DataSource` of the `BindingSource`.

Comment: I've tried the second one beforehand and followed the tutorial but it doesn't work. It's not updating anything: "This causes boilerplate code to be generated that displays the data that originates in the data store to the user. [...] If you pressed F5 on the application, the data from the underlying database would appear in the forms controls."

Comment: The way that I described is not related to `DataSource` at all. It's completely  related to WCF and uses your model classes.  I have used this way multiple times and it's completely reliable and rapid. If you remember the way which we worked with `DataSet`, this way is really like that but using WCF services and Models.

Comment: The updated answer contains all options which you can use. All of them works properly and you can choose either of them. If you are interested to use code based configurations yourself, the second option is suitable for you. The 3rd performs the same thing for you, but with designer support. And also the first is the most simple :)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem i had was to understand that i could drag and drop the textboxes into the UI and how to actually do stuff with it. Now it seems to be working because i've added the following code to my previous:

```
   private void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();  
        int valueParsed;
        if(txt_KNr.TextLength == 6)
        {
            if(Int32.TryParse(txt_KNr.Text.Trim(), out valueParsed))
            {
                Service svc = new Service();
                WcfServiceGVO.CustomerData data = svc.Connect(txt_KNr.Text);
                customerDataBindingSource.DataSource = data;
                //txt_FirstName.DataBindings.Add("Text", data, "FirstName");
                //txt_LastName.DataBindings.Add("Text", data, "LastName");
                //txt_Street.DataBindings.Add("Text", data, "Street");
                //txt_PLZ.DataBindings.Add("Text", data, "PLZ");
                //txt_Location.DataBindings.Add("Text", data, "Location");
                //lbl_ampErg.DataBindings.Add("Text", data, "Ampel");                    
            }   
}
```

the key was to understand that i could just use my servicedata as a DataSource! Thanks Reza for the great help!